# Use GCN-LSTM to generate descriptions for scenes represented by graphs

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, lstm, relationship

Given a scene, I retrieve objects contained in it with an object detector. Next, I identify the potential unary (one object) and binary (a pair of objects) visual relationships in this scene (using specialized classifiers) by specifying the most likely attribute for each unary relationship (e.g. Object `Cat` with attribute `"Sitting"`, which means that `"The cat is sitting"`) and the most likely predicate for each binary relationship (e.g. A pair of objects `[Cup - Table]` with the predicate `"On"`, which means that `"The cup is on the table"`).

All of these defined relationships are modeled by an oriented graph with the form:

- Each node represents an object of the scene (with its id).
- Each defined unary relation (attribute) is modeled by a loop (an arrow, from a node to itself, with the corresponding attribute).
- Each defined binary relation is modeled by an arrow, from a node (left side of the relation) to another (right side of the relation), with the corresponding predicate.

The figure below shows an example of the relationship graph construction from a scene. The latter contains four objects: `"cup 1"`, `"cup 2"`, `"cat"` and a `"table"`. The defined relationships are:

- Unary relations (only one): For the `"cat"` object (`"standing"`).
- Binary relationships (5 relationships): Three with the predicate `"on"` (`[Cat - Table]`, `[Cup 1 - Table]`, `[Cup 2 - Table]`) and two with the predicate `"next to"` (`[Cat - Cup 1]`, `[Cat - Cup 2]`).

[image: Generated visual relationships graph from a scene]

The goal is to train a `GCN-LSTM` which receives (in input) the previous graph and returns (in output) a description (which corresponds to this graph, and therefore, to the initial scene).

The training of this `GCN-LSTM` is done by creating, for each training scene, its graph (the input) and the output is its description (a paragraph). E.g. For the previous figure, the description (for training) is: `"The cat standing on the table is next to a couple of cups"`. The process for the previous example is shown in the figure below.

[image: GCN-LSTM: Input and output]

I looked for implementation examples of `GCN-LSTM` (in particular, in the documentation of [`StellarGraph`](https://github.com/stellargraph/stellargraph)) for a similar problem, but I found nothing. So, I wanted to know, is there a way to build such a model using [`StellarGraph`](https://github.com/stellargraph/stellargraph)? if yes, how? else, which tool can help me to build this model?

Answer (score 1):

GCN-LSTM is designed for encoding graphs with node features that are sequences, and doing forecasting on those sequences. In this case, it looks like you might be trying to encode a graph with fixed features and then use that encoding to generate a sentence.

For this, an appropriate model would be to use a graph classification model, such as [`GCNSupervisedGraphClassification`](https://stellargraph.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#stellargraph.layer.GCNSupervisedGraphClassification) or [`DeepGraphCNN`](https://stellargraph.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#stellargraph.layer.DeepGraphCNN). These can be used to encode a graph to an vector for input into a separate LSTM decoder.

Notably, these models cannot easily incorporate edge features/types, so some aspects of the `on`/`next to`/`standing` modelling would have to be adjusted; such as being incorporated into the nodes as features.

For instance, one can replace the final `Dense(units=1, activation="sigmoid")` layer (or more of the `Dense` layers) in https://stellargraph.readthedocs.io/en/stable/demos/graph-classification/gcn-supervised-graph-classification.html#Create-the-Keras-graph-classification-model with a more complicated decoder model (i.e. LSTM).

(This answer is copied from my response to a very similar (the same?) question asked on the StellarGraph community forum: [original](https://community.stellargraph.io/t/use-gcn-lstm-to-generate-descriptions-for-scenes-represented-by-graphs/170), [archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20200716034929/https://community.stellargraph.io/t/use-gcn-lstm-to-generate-descriptions-for-scenes-represented-by-graphs/170).)